# Regex not finding string

Tags: java, regex

I am having issues with this code:
For some reason, it always fails to match the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pluginList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("");
    String findMe = "plugins".concat(FILE_SEPARATOR).concat(pluginList.get(i));

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("("+name.getPath()+")(.*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(findMe);

    // Check if the current plugin matches the string.
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return !pluginListMode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. Oh, and for readability, change your return statement part to `return !pluginListMode;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need is

```
return ("plugins"+FILE_SEPARATOR+pluginName).indexOf(name.getPath()) != -1;
```

But your code also makes no sense due to the fact that there's no way for that `for`-loop to enter a second iteration -- it returns unconditionally. So more probably you need something like this:

```
for (String pluginName : pluginList)
  if (("plugins"+FILE_SEPARATOR+pluginName).indexOf(name.getPath()) != -1)
    return false;
return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now we can only guess since we don't know what `name.getPath()` might return.

I suspect it fails because that string might contain characters that have special meaning inside regexes. Try it again with

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("("+Pattern.quote(name.getPath())+")(.*)");
```

and see what happens then.

Also the `(.*)` part (and even the parentheses around your `name.getPath()` result) don't appear to matter at all since you're not doing anything with the result of the match itself. At which point the question is why you're using a regex in the first place.

Comment: I was not able to get regular expressions working.
I have tried what you suggested, but nothing seemed to work.
I used the option below to resolve this, thanks anyway.